# deploying the web application to server for android

Tags: android, web-applications, cordova

I developed a web application using phone gap framework for android platform. I only have single file called index.html, so i copied both the index.html and phonegap.js(from framework) files to the server and ran them from emulator. then i'm getting an error as below

```
02-24 10:46:42.540: WARN/browser(277): Console: Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: PluginManager http://192.168.1.25:8084/web2/phonegap.js:552
```

In index.html file i wrote a code to play a stream from the internet using the Media class, that i have seen in the documentation of phonegap and it worked in emulator by installing the apk. I guess the error is not because of the Media or the code, i guess i'm not deploying the web app correctly because i left the phonepap.0.9.4.jar because i don't know where to include this file in the server. I use Tomcat and i'm deploying this in WebRoot folder..

Please help me in deploying this project(the procedure how to deploy and how user can view the page in device browser).. Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PhoneGap framework does not work in this way, you should put both phonegap.0.9.4.jar and phonegap.js on your mobile device, instead of on a remote server.

Comment: hi,
yes its not working, would you please give me overview or any link about this? In phonegap site i only see publishing the application to market. but i want to deploy in server, and it has to work from browser not as a separate application by installing apk.. The main concept is that when user types the web address, web page has to be displayed and stream has to be played.. How can i put both phonegap.jar and phonegap.js in every device? Please advice.. Thank you..

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot use phonegap without letting user install the apk. However, SenchaTouch and jQTouch suits your requirements. You can write HTML5 applications with these frameworks and without asking user install any apk.

Comment: oh, really, i am disappointed now.. Since this framework is for web application it should work from server not from apk, they should have developed this phonegap to support that.. Anyway thank you for your answer and helping me by advising other frame works..